# Coordinating Conjunction vs subordinating conjunction. Who, Which Vs and it/that

Tags: conjunctions, clauses, relative-pronouns

I have a question about conjunctions, dependent and independent clauses.

The issue came up when a text book suggests that "and it" can replace "which/who". 
But my understanding is that subordinating conjunctions are used for connecting dependent clauses, whilst coordinating conjunctions are used with independent clauses.

So here are some examples.

1. This book is about King Sejong, who invented Hangeul.
2. This book is about King Sejong and he invented Hangeul.

No.1 to me is correct whilst 2. isn't.

Another example however

1. The word shampoo comes from the Hindi word champo, which means "to press".
2. The word shampoo comes from the Hindi word champo and it means "to press".

In this case, both look correct to me.

In the 1st example, is it incorrect because the subordinate clause acts as a adjective clause, whilst the 2nd example isn't?

One final example that is obviously wrong:

1. I am reading a book about Paris, which I visited two years ago.
2. I am reading a book about Paris and I visited two years ago.

Thank you.

Comment: The whole point of having relative clauses is to avoid having to use your examples with "and".

Comment: For clarification, is the avoidance of "and" because of the potential for confusion in the meaning of the sentence? Or is there a clear grammar mistake? Some sentences seem to make sense whilst others just doesn't sound right.